# C - Limit struct Scope

Tags: c, struct, scope

I am having this structure in a .c file:

```
struct entry {
    int position;
    int length;
    struct entry *node;
};
```

Now, how can I limit the scope of this structure *layout* to the host file, so that when using the same name for a new structure *layout* in another file, I don't get 'redefinition' error?

I tried using *static* before *struct*, but it seems of no use (I also doesn't make sense). BTW, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059800/why-do-structure-definitions-have-internal-linkage) doesn't seem valid to me, as that I get 'redefinition' error when duplicating *stuct entry* across linked files (using MinGW).

--- Edit ---
For those who want to know more: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793952/understanding-c-namespaces).

Comment: can you show the exact error message being show when you try to compile/link your program

Comment: error: redefinition of "struct entry". It is because that I included the file to another that uses the same name. It appears it is a logical error of isolating design from implementation, in which translation units need only to communicate through header files, not directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't get a redefinition error.  Types are local to *translation units*, and don't have any visibility.  Only functions and data objects have visibility.

If you're getting a redefinition error, you must be using that name in a header or other included file so it ends up in the same translation unit.

Comment: ...or are including a file with a struct, union, or enum of that name.

Comment: This was my problem: "if you're getting a redefinition error, you must be using that name in a header or other included file so it ends up in the same translation unit."

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ecatmur - So this is wrong: http://www.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/cscout/doc/name.html ? It wouldn't shock me, but does annoy me. I didn't have a C99 standard handy to double-check it with.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong; 6.2.3 footnote 24: "There is only one name space for tags even though three are possible."

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to have `struct entry` mean different things in different files.  That's fine: just put the codes for defining each version of the struct in different `.c` files, and make sure to never include a c file from another c file
or include a c file from a header file.

Only one definition of the struct should exist in each translation unit.